# Drupal 8 theming, block-order/block-weight is ignored by theme (?)

Tags: block, drupal-8, theming

i build a Drupal 8 theme from the scratch. Problem: The block-order/block-weight i set in the backend gets ignored by my theme in the frontend.

If i switch to the themes "seven" or "bartik" the ordering/weight of the blocks is correct in the frontend. Seems like im missing something in my theme-settings. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance and regards,
Fab

Comment: ok - i came closer to the solution: The problem is, that i create pages via "views" that have a dedicated URL. And it seems that Drupal doesnt put that content into the "main content"-Block. So i am not able to put other blocks above or beyond the content by changing the weight of the "main-content" block. 

Can someone gimme a hint on that?

Answer (score 1):

ok solved it:

For some reason i had to re-add the "main-content" block to the "content-region" and delete the old. Maybe for the first the content had no weight or ... i dunno. But after that its working fine!